# How to use VSCode regexp to find all ocurrences of \cite without ~?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, latex

I need to find in several files of my thesis all occurrences of `any text\cite{...}` and change them to `any text~\cite{...}`.  But I don't understand how VSCode search regexp works.

I have tried `^[!~]\cite` but it doesn't seem to understand this notation for a char that is not `~`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is it the replacement in the current document, or in many files? If you are replacing in a single open document, you can use a lookbehind solution, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
([^~]|^)(\\cite)
```

Replace with `$1~$2`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QJIhX7/2).

*Details*:

- `([^~]|^)` - Group 1: any char other than `~` (`[^~]`) or (`|`) a start of a line
- `(\\cite)` - Group 2: `\cite` text.

The `$1~$2` replacement pattern uses Group 1 + `~` + Group 2 value to replace the matches.

Comment: Nice.  I didn't know that in replace I could just use `$1~\\cite`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Wiktors answer could be:

```
(?<!~)(\\cite)
```

And replace with:

```
~$1
```

`(?<!~)` is a negative lookbehind forcing the regex to only match something *not* starting with a tilde (~). `(\\cite)` matches the text literally, where the parentheses creates a capture group.

In the replacement first you add the tilde you want added, followed by `$1` which is a back reference, meaning "take capture group 1 and put here".

Groups are numbered from 0 (which is the entire match). And is numbered from outside in, left to right. The negative lookbehind is not a capture group.